# Parsing RSS possible dates RFC 822/8339 and ISO 8601?

Tags: java, android, date, time, rss

I've been working on a feed reader app, and i need to parse de pubDate from RSS and Atom. According to RSS protocol the pubDate should be in RFC 822 format however i found some RSS publishers with different date formats, this is the way i'm doing it so far, not sure if it's the best way, advices are appreciated:

Relevant code here:

```
//List that keeps the data formats allowed
private static List<String> formats;

static {
    formats = Arrays.asList(
            //RFC 822 possible formats
            "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", //Sun, 19 May 2002 15:21:36 GMT
            "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm zzz", // Sun, 19 May 2002 15:21 GMT
            "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", // Sun, 19 May 2002 15:21:36
            "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm", // Sun, 19 May 2002 15:21
            "d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz",  // 19 May 2002 15:21:36 GMT
            "d MMM yyyy HH:mm zzz", // 19 May 2002 15:21 GMT
            "d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", // 19 May 2002 15:21:36
            "d MMM yyyy HH:mm", // 19 May 2002 15:21
            //RFC 8339
            "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZ", // 1996-12-19T16:39:57-0800
            "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSSZZZ", // 1937-01-01T12:00:27.87+0020
            "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss", // 1937-01-01T12:00:27
            //ISO 8601 same as RFC8339 but it allows to ommit the 'T' and replace it with a ' '.
            "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ssZZZ", // 1996-12-19 16:39:57-0800
            "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss.SSSZZZ", // 1937-01-01 12:00:27.87+0020
            "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss" // 1937-01-01 12:00:27
    );

}

/*
 Parses a string with a date and returns the milliseconds. The RSS standard says that dates are
 formatted according to RFC 822 however some are in RFC 3339 or ISO6091 format, so a brute force
 approach is made to parse the date, if it fails null is returned;
 */
public static Long getDateFromString( String date){

    for(String format: formats){

        //Creates SimpleDateFormat with US Locale as recommend in google docs to parse the input
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);

        try{
              return sdf.parse(date).getTime();
        }catch (ParseException ex){
            Log.i("Utils","Wrong date format: inputDate: " +date + " format: " + format);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

It's on Android, so using Joda-Time is not an option because as far as i know it suffers from slow initialization and it's a huge library.
Also i know SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe but that doesn't matter in my case.

Thanks in advance.